# Hyperledger Sawtooth docker container "settings tp" not working

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I have set up a network with 4 validator using docker compose and it is using PBFT consensus.

If i try to submit a proposal to change a setting, for example the "sawtooth.validator.transaction_families" settings, nothing happens (I'm doing it from the validator container using "sawtooth proposal create" ). Did someone have similar problems?

Moreover If i enter inside the settings TP docker container I can't see the folder with logs. Does someone know why the settings TP is not creating logs?

Comment: Can you please provide the logs?

Comment: There are no logs on the validator debug log neither in the TP docker container (the logs file in this container is not even created). This is the strange thing.

Comment: I assume you're using `--url` along with the command. What does the command `sawtooth proposal create` output on the terminal?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that I was not using the `--url` so maybe that was the cause. However after I ran the command I got nothing as output. The command just ran.

Comment: That could be an issue. It never submitted the transaction. The CLI default points to localhost, however when you run these through the docker-compose, you will have to use the service name of the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Probably seems to be an issue when running the command without the `--url` option inside the shell container. So, probably the transaction never got submitted.

If you run these commands be sure that you are using the `--url` option with the right host